# blog post not displaying using HTML

Tags: html, tags, blogs, blogger

I am running a blog on blogger. I used `</head>` tag in my blog posts and when I published this posts, It was not showing on front end (On opening post in browser). Some more html codes when I use they just don't show in front end. When I open post to edit them again, it doesn't show those html space. Blank space is inserted at their place.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Right now your question is very off topic and will likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include HTML in your blog posts use the Blogger post editor in "HTML" Mode and copy & paste the code you want to include within <pre> or <code> tags.

For example

```
<pre>
 </head>
</pre>

<code>
 </head>
</code>
```

However you first have to escape the code (for example using tools [like this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html)) within the pre/code tags like this in order for being correctly displayed:

```
<pre>
 &lt;/head&gt;
</pre>

<code>
 &lt;/head&gt;
</code>
```